# Why is the Apache CXF dynamic client returning null for typeClass information in certain SOAP operations?

Tags: cxf

In our software I have to provide dynamic SOAP support. For this purpose, I am using Apache CXF (version 3.5.0 since we still have to support Java 8). I followed the principles from  wsdl_first_dynamic_client sample. Everything works fine for some WSDLs. But for instance for the WSDL from http://www.thomas-bayer.com/axis2/services/BLZService?wsdl the typeClass information is null.

```
  @Test
  void testBlzService() throws Exception {
    ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();

    URL url = new URL("http://www.thomas-bayer.com/axis2/services/BLZService?wsdl");

    DynamicClientFactory dcf = DynamicClientFactory.newInstance();

    Client client = dcf.createClient(url, classLoader);

    Endpoint endpoint = client.getEndpoint();
    ServiceInfo serviceInfo = endpoint.getService().getServiceInfos().get(0);

    Class<?> inputClass =
          serviceInfo
                .getBindings()
                .iterator()
                .next()
                .getOperations()
                .iterator()
                .next()
                .getInput()
                .getMessageParts()
                .get(0)
                .getTypeClass();
    
    // inputClass is null here, I have no programmatically way to figure out the type parameter!
    
    // But the generated client works anyhow!
    ClassLoader newClassLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();

    Class<?> getBankTypeClass = newClassLoader.loadClass("com.thomas_bayer.blz.GetBankType");
    
    Object getBankType = getBankTypeClass.newInstance();
    
    Field blzField = getBankTypeClass.getDeclaredField("blz");
    blzField.setAccessible(true);
    blzField.set(getBankType, "21450000");
    
    Object[] result = client.invoke(serviceInfo
          .getBindings()
          .iterator()
          .next()
          .getOperations()
          .iterator()
          .next()
          .getInput()
          .getBindingOperation(),
          getBankType);

    client.destroy();
  }
```

Am I doing something wrong? Do I have to set some configuration parameters or is there an alternative way to figure out the types of the parameters for a web service call?